# UPSERT multiple statements at once Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some random update statements such as this:

```
UPDATE tab1 SET a = 'a', b = 'b' WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE tab2 SET c= = 'c' WHERE id = 2;
UPDATE tab1 SET a = 'a', d = 'd' WHERE id = 3;
.
.
.
UPDATE tab1 SET a = 'a', b = 'b' WHERE id = 100;
```

I need to upsert these multiple statements inside of PLSQL. I found syntax to upsert one at a time:

```
begin
   insert into tab1 (a,b); 
      values ('a', 'b');
exception
   when dup_val_on_index then
      UPDATE tab SET a = 'a', b = 'b' WHERE id = 1;
end
```

I am not concerned about concurrency, I have many update statements I need to insert at once (at once because I am using Oracle APEX and have just one pl/sql sheet to do all of this).

```
TAB1:
| ID | A | B | D |

TAB2:
| ID | D |
```

Comment: Use **[MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9016.htm)**

Comment: @lad2025 I looked into merge, but it seems it is for updating multiple tables which have a relationship? There always seems to be a join between two tables, which i don't have.

Comment: `Merge` can solved your problem. just provide table structure and sample data.

Comment: @user2924127 Prepare http://sqlfiddle.com, you can use CTE/subquery for second table like `SELECT 'a' AS a, 'b' AS b, null AS c, null AS d FROM dual UNION ALL SELECT null, null, 'c, null FROM dual ... `

Comment: @RubahMalam I have gave a structure. There are two tables. Each will have some statements that need to be upserted into (although the the two tables are in no way connected)

Comment: @lad2025 I tried the fiddle, but I can't seem to create multiple tables?

Comment: @user2924127 Add `;` and newline

Comment: @lad2025  I tried : create table tabone
( a varchar2(200),
  b varchar2(200),
  d varchar2(200)
);
create table tabtwo
( c varchar2(200)
); But I get an error there is an invalid character

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will be easier to explain with an answer.

Take a look at this MERGE statement

```
  MERGE INTO tab1 tab1      
      USING   
         (SELECT  'a' a,  'b' b, null c, null d, 1 id from dual
         UNION ALL
         SELECT null a, null b, 'c' c, null d, 2 id from dual
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'a' a, null b, null c, 'd' d, 3 id from dual
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'a' a, 'b' b, null c, null d, 100 id from dual) my_table
  ON ( tab1.id = my_table.id)
  WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET tab1.a=my_table.a, tab1.b=my_table.b, 
    tab1.c=my_table.c, tab1.d=my_table.d
  WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (id, a, b, c, d) 
     VALUES (my_table.id, my_table.a, my_table.b, my_table.c, my_table.d)
```

I am not using any second database table, I'm simply using values that you supplied in your example above:

```
UPDATE tab1 SET a = 'a', b = 'b' WHERE id = 1;
UPDATE tab2 SET c= = 'c' WHERE id = 2;
UPDATE tab1 SET a = 'a', d = 'd' WHERE id = 3;
.
.
.
UPDATE tab1 SET a = 'a', b = 'b' WHERE id = 100;
```

That becomes "my_table".   Then you can update or insert accordingly.

I'm not 100% what is the unique value in your example above.

You insert only column (a,b) but then update based on the id column if dup_val_on_index...what are the unique constraints on tab1?

Comment: Thank you very much this is much more clear! I provided a simple example of my problem, but what if I have multiple conditions for the where statement?

Comment: The main thing is just to have the data supplied, and to understand where the WHERE clause goes in a merge statement. http://psoug.org/reference/merge.html