# Upsert (insert or update) list of objects with MyBatis XML annotation

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, mybatis

I'm trying to update or insert based on whether a value in a certain column exists or not.

I am using Oracle and below is the query I have:

```
MERGE INTO EMPLOYEE emp
USING (SELECT #{employeeId, jdbcType=VARCHAR} AS EMPLOYEE_ID 
       FROM dual) inholder
ON (inholder.EMPLOYEE_ID = emp.EMPLOYEE_ID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
               UPDATE SET emp.EMPLOYEE_NAME = #{employeeName, jdbcType=VARCHAR}
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
               INSERT 
                   (EMPLOYEE_ID, EMPLOYEE_NAME)
               VALUE
                   (#{employeeId, jdbcType=VARCHAR}, #{employeeName, jdbcType=VARCHAR})
```

I have a list of employee objects getting passed, but I am not sure how to pass the list in order to do a multi insert/update

I tried using foreach like below, but was not able to get it to work and ensure that the update and insert is one query versus multiple separate queries

```
<foreach item="employee" index="index" collection="employeeList">

.
.
.

</foreach>
```

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32770261/1261766) might help. If not, please show us how you use `<foreach>` in SQL statement. BTW, if you have to deal with many objects, you should consider using [batch processing](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-code-a-batch-insert) instead of `<foreach>` for performance reason.